# Detect: USB 3.0 Type C / USB 3.1 type C "gen1" / USB 3.1 type C "gen2"

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I'd like to connect 2 monitors to my System76 Laptop.  DisplayLink (USB 2.0) doesn't work with Wayland, so I'd like to try the USB type C port.

I'm looking at devices and they say USB 3.1 Type C.  System76 says it has 1x USB 3.0 Type C, which I read in the internet was renamed "3.1 gen1".

Generally, how can I detect which is which from the linux command line without relying on the marketing speak?

Specifically, here's an example of what I've got:

```
☀  sudo lsusb -t            
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

And the details:

```
☀  sudo lsusb -v
```

https://zerobin.net/?e7bed30c27e1392e#tononX/pExWrArQ/uZwC5lOjK3WMC6wvWrg9gR3+hy4=

Specifically, I'd like to know if the laptop is compatible with these devices to display multiple monitors:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01KCBZFJ2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KCBZFJ2)
[https://www.amazon.com/CalDigit-USB-C-Docking-Station-DisplayPort/dp/B01AX6J7P4/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AX6J7P4)

Generally, I'd like to know how to map the marketing speak to the output of the command line.

Thanks!

Comment: The Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI adapter in  your link isn't for a conventional PC / Laptop. There are other ones you can look at. Sometimes the PC / laptop manufacturer will write drivers for the Thunderbolt 3 interface. Have you made any recent progress?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an answer (if you have one, I'll mark it correct).  I bought a solution by trying the new 5900 version of the chip and a different manufacturer: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B074ZJ143Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074ZJ143Q)